# expect to test url #fragment with protractor and jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to use protractor (with jasmine) to do some functional tests for my web application, and one of problem I came across is:

**how to check what is the current hash (#fragment) in my url?**

for example using, `browser.get('/')` it should navigate to `http://localhost:8000/#/` url ... where `#/` is the url #fragment (the hash) that is used by angular when html5 mode is not enabled.

the `browser.getCurrentUrl()` will return the absolute url since `http://` and not just the fragment which I want to test.

is there a way to test this case in a correct way?

I would expect to do something like this:

```js
browser.get('/');
expect(browser.getCurrentUrlFragment()).toBe('#/');

browser.get('/user/');
expect(browser.getCurrentUrlFragment()).toBe('#/user');
```

is that possible?

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple matchers can be used in this case, for example `toMatch()` with a `$` at the end:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/#\/user$/);
```

Or, `toEndWith()` matcher from [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) third-party:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEndWith("#/user");
```

The built-in `toContain()` could also be used, but this would not enforce the substring to be expected at the end of the string:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("#/user");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use built-in object - `document.location.hash`. It will return only hash, or empty string if url doesn't contain it.

Look up `Location` object - it contains a few other methods for retrieving url parts.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not close to what OP is asking about. This is protractor and jasmine specific.

Comment: @alecxe is right, this method will work when a simple check should be made. but could not work when using angularjs when you have to deal with promises (like on page change / page load) ... and will make pointless the usage of protractor/jasmine framework.

Comment: pure js is so cute and convenient, i don't know why frameworks are so popular.